# TCXO output load, and shaping circuit

Tags: tcxo

I'm looking at the following datasheet for an accurate TCXO: [TG2016SBN](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2045487.pdf?_ga=2.124867338.1679259088.1524846055-1777858039.1518268230&_gac=1.144895360.1523515068.EAIaIQobChMIv5_s6o-02gIV5p3tCh2rMA0gEAQYASABEgJKVfD_BwE)

It gives values for Rload and Cload, and AC coupling cap - which I've incorporated into a clock pulsing circuit. Will a simple comparator (with a bit of hysteris) be enough to clean this signal up for a CMOS clock input?

I've currently got the following circuit sketched up. The 20Ks should will give a paralel (small signal) load of 10K, and bias it at 1.65V DC coupled. I don't see anything wrong with it - the comparator is fast enough and in theory work.

[image]

The comparator is the following: [LT6752](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2281793.pdf?_ga=2.193733678.264505857.1522266899-1777858039.1518268230&_gac=1.247270960.1522339446.EAIaIQobChMIwfvcq_SR2gIVCZztCh2DoQ1rEAAYASAAEgJ69PD_BwE)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To avoid non 50:50 duty cycles on the output of the (excellent) comparator you have picked, I would directly feed one input from the TXCO and use a 10 k resistor feeding the other input with that "other" input being connected to a 10 nF capacitor to ground. Same story as a data slicer: -

[image]

This ensures your DC levels are set the same and the tolerance of all those 20 k resistors is not a factor any more.

Comment: Hmm, non 50:50 duty cycles aren't really a problem in my application, just counting those edges. I'll take look at the impedances that the crystal is seeing as they seem to be pretty strictly specced out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've had to interface 0.8V p-p clipped TCXO to CMOS several times.  I've always found a 1nF AC coupling cap, and resistive biasing using a divider around the 200K level works fine.

For instance in this case for using a TXCO to replace the main RPi crystal.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74482/switch-out-the-x1-oscillator-on-a-rpi-2-3